# Proper way to replace the_content only for pages created by custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pages, filters, the-content

I'm creating a plugin that needs to replace `the_content` of only two specific pages that it created upon activation.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'emd_content');  

function emd_content() {
  if ( is_page('Member Directory') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-members.php'; 
    }
    elseif ( is_page('Contact Members') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-member-contact-form.php'; 
    }
    else {
        the_content();
    }
}
```

The code above gives me a `500 Internal Server Error` for pages other than `Member Directory` and `Contact Members`, which both work properly.

If I remove `else { the_content(); }`, then the `Member Directory` and `Contact Members` work correctly, but all other pages don't display anything where `the_content` should be displayed.

I also tried wrapping the `add_filter()` within `if(is_page('Member Directory') || is_page('Contact Members')) {  }`. `the_content` worked for other pages, but not for the two created by the plugin.

**What is a better/proper way to replace `the_content` for these two pages using my plugin?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the filtered content, try like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'emd_content');  

function emd_content( $content ) {
  if ( is_page('Member Directory') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-members.php'; 
    }
    elseif ( is_page('Contact Members') ) {
      include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-member-contact-form.php'; 
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

But the better way is to use [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files) for those pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is so similar to the solution I decided to go with that I accepted it as the correct answer. I read elsewhere that custom page templates are recommended for this, but it just seems like overkill when just needing to replace content for two pages. Thanks again!

Comment: The link to the "custom page template" is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Ashok's answer works, but I also found the following, which is what I decided to go with.

> In a nutshell, a `filter` must always return a value - `the_content()`
>   just echos and is likely causing an infinite loop since it would call
>   your filter.

```
function emd_content($content) {
  if ( is_page('Member Directory') ) {
      $content = include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-members.php'; 
    }
    elseif ( is_page('Contact Members') ) {
      $content = include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content-member-contact-form.php'; 
    }
    else {
      $content = $content;
    }
      return $content;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `else { $content = $content }` redundant? If we didn't change the content in the first if or in the elseif, it hasn't changed so just  return it as it was passed to the function.